# Autocomplete with php and sql

Tags: php, sql, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete code tidbit that searches my database across one field, and returns the value from the user input.  How can I alter this so that it returns in this case the entire product table line(cost, retail, model, etc) instead of just the model #, and upon clicking it, selects those values in a form that can be modified?  Here is the code I have as of yet :

database call code :

```
<?php

// We will use PDO to execute database stuff. 
// This will return the connection to the database and set the parameter
// to tell PDO to raise errors when something bad happens
function getDbConnection() {
  $db = new PDO(DB_DRIVER . ":dbname=" . DB_DATABASE . ";host=" . DB_SERVER . ";charset=utf8", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
  return $db;
}

// This is the 'search' function that will return all possible rows starting with the keyword sent by the user
function serachForKeyword($keyword) {

    $db = getDbConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT model as product FROM `products` WHERE model LIKE ? ORDER BY product");

    $keyword = $keyword . '%';
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);

    $isQueryOk = $stmt->execute();

    $results = array();

    if ($isQueryOk) {
      $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    } else {

      trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $db = null; 

    return $results;
}
```

autocomplete call :

```
<?php
require('constant.php');
require('database.php');

if (!isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
    die("");
}

$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
$data = serachForKeyword($keyword);
echo json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

index page :

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Auto-complete tutorial</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="auto-complete.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" id="keyword" list="datalist">
    <div id="results">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just a push in the right direction would be extremely helpful.  I imagine the pseudocode to make this work as imagined would be something as follows :

$bindtorow = $keyword + ($id, $k1, $description, $cost, $retail)
$keyword = $k1 = $userinput
upon search echo $bindtorow (id of keyword, description of keyword, etc)
upon click attach (id,$k1, description, etc) to :
id
model
etc.

Thanks!

PDO Code that is nonworking :

```
<?php
require_once"database.php";//connection to database
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search']){
    $search=$_POST['search'];
} elseif(isset($_GET['search']) && $_GET['search']){
    $search=$_GET['search'];
}

if(isset($search)){
    $search = '%' . strtr($search, ['%' => '\%', '_' => '\_']);
    $search = str_replace(" ", "%", $search);
    $search= "%$search%";

    $sql="select * from products where `model` LIKE ? OR `category` LIKE ? LIMIT 10";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute([$search, $search]);
```

and....

```
<?php
class Database 
{
    private static $dbName = 'a' ; 
    private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
    private static $dbUsername = 'b';
    private static $dbUserPassword = 'c';

    private static $cont  = null;

    public function __construct() {
        exit('Init function is not allowed');
    }

    public static function connect()
    {
       // One connection through whole application
       if ( null == self::$cont )
       {      
        try 
        {
          self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword);  
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) 
        {
          die($e->getMessage());  
        }
       } 
       return self::$cont;
    }

    public static function disconnect()
    {
        self::$cont = null;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you not just alter the query in your `serachForKeyword` function ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 do you have an example?

Comment: I do not have an example. Currently you are just selecting `model` column in your query in that function. Why not modify that query to select the columns that you need in addition to `model` ?